# Xamarin - Customrenderer getting 2 errors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've been getting these errors in my CustomSwitchRenderer class which is located in SalesKicker.Droid. Here are the errors:

> OnElementCHanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e): no suitable method found to override

and

> Android.Widget.Switch cannot be used as typ parameter 'TElement' in the genericc type or method ElementChangedEventArgs'  There is no implicit referencee conversion from Widget.Switch to Forms.Element

I'm very confused since this worked before, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Here is my class:

```
public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.TextOn = "AAN";
            Control.TextOff = "UIT";

            Color colorON = Color.Green;
            Color colorOFF = Color.Red;

            Control.SetTextColor(Color.Black);

            StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();

            drawable.AddState(new int[] 
                {
                    Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked
                }, new ColorDrawable(colorON));
            drawable.AddState(new int[]
                {

                }, new ColorDrawable(colorOFF));

            Control.ThumbDrawable = drawable; 
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, I also added this line:

```
using Switch = Android.Widget.Switch
```

And this ofcourse:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Switch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `using Switch = Xamarin.Forms.Switch` instead of `using Switch = Android.Widget.Switch`

Comment: Well, that was quick! Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: the switch doesn't show in my app, what is going wrong here?